# Finding the next ActiveRecord model object in the database using given object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have an ActiveRecord model object `@gallery` which represents a row in the Galleries MYSQL table. Is there a way for me to ask `@gallery` to give me the id to the next gallery object in the table?

The obvious way for me to do this is to :

```
@galleries = Gallery.find(:all)
index = @galleries.index(@gallery)

@nextgallery = @galleries[index+1]
```

but then I have to nilsafe this and I'm unnecessarily making another DB call to fetch all records.
Any other way out?

Answer (score 8):

I've been in similar situation and I end up with couple solutions using Rails 3.1.3, with either class methods or scope (named_scope in Rails 2.x). This approach will work even with not sequential ids.

Class methods example using a Post model:

```
def next
  Post.where("posts.id > ?", self.id).order("posts.id ASC").limit(1)
end

def previous
  Post.where("posts.id < ?", self.id).order("posts.id DESC").limit(1)
end
```

This could be used like:

```
post = Post.find(5)

next_post = post.next
 => [#<Post id: 6, ...]

previous_post = post.previous
 => [#<Post id: 4, ...]
```

And for scopes, using lambda should be something like:

```
  scope :next, lambda { |i| {:conditions => ["#{self.table_name}.id > ?", i.id], :order => "#{self.table_name}.id ASC", :limit => 1} }
  scope :previous, lambda { |i| {:conditions => ["#{self.table_name}.id < ?", i.id], :order => "#{self.table_name}.id DESC", :limit => 1} }
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you really sure that you're making a second db call? If so, does it really matter? Is this deep in a 4x nested loop where every call matters?

If not, pre-optimizing may be your downfall. AR:B does a lot of caching and iirc find(:all) returns an array or Hash so index+1 should be okay.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should define some criteria to decide order of your galleries. In MySQL when you will do

```
 SELECT * FROM galeries
```

it can give you different order of returned records. So, for example, if you order them by creation time then you can do something like this:

```
 @nextgallery = Gallery.find(
                   :first, 
                   :order => "created_at ASC", 
                   :conditions => "created_at > #{@gallery.created_at}"
                 )
```

In this example you should be careful with `@gallery.created_at` because Rails stores in database time in GMT +0 time format, but in `@gallery.created_at` it is with your local configuration (for example +2 h). To change it use: `@gallery.created_at.gmtime.to_s`

Answer (score 0):

The code you presented is a good thing to do. The `find(:all)` method fetches by default all records of the galleries table, in the following way (you can see it when running WEBrick in development mode)

```
SELECT * FROM galleries
```

The results of this query are cached and reused every time you access @galaeries, this is also visible (when running WEBrick) since no other database calls are made.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way to get the next gallery from your @gallery instance without hitting the database.

You could however only hit the database once if you did something like

```
@galleries = Gallery.find(:all)
@gallery = @galleries.detect{|g| g.id == params[:gallery_id]}
index = @galleries.index(@gallery)
@nextgallery = @galleries[index+1]
```

Hence you only hit the database once. This is only bad if you have a large number of galleries, in which case it would make sense to write a `next` method to your gallery which does hit the database